# numPy - Select column from structured dtype

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I am using `np.genfromtxt` to read in data of mixed type from an external file:

```
data = np.genfromtxt(filename, dtype='U10,U8,f,f,f,f,f,f')
```

If the type of my data was homogeneous, I could then access column 2 of my data by doing `column_two = data[:,2]`. However, since I am using a structured dtype, I can't simply do `data[:,2]`, as this results in an `IndexError: too many indices for array`. Is there any way I can efficiently select the nth column of `data`, to use in further processing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue is structured datatypes do not support column indexing. The way I found to rectify it, and the way that feels most organic, is to use ["Field Access"](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#field-access), viz.

```
data = np.genfromtxt(filename, dtype=[('date', str), ('time', str), ('az', np.float64), ...)
```

This way, to access the "time" column, we may simply use `data['time']`.